# C# extract property from list of objects

Tags: c#, list, properties

If I have a list of objects that have a property, how can I extract a list of of all of those properties?

IE given the following object

```
class C{
    public string name{get;set;}
}
```

and a list of `C`, how can I get a list of `C.Name`?

Comment: You mean to ***select*** all the names? Perhaps using LINQ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ListOfC.Select(c => c.name).ToList();
```

`Select` is a transform function, it returns a new `IEnumerable` based on the selector it is given. As you specifically want a `List`, you need to cast it to a `List` afterwards.